# What happens when weak referenced object is put itno HashMap as key?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is my program :

```
public class MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference {

    private Map<MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference, Integer> map = null;
    public MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference() {
        map = new HashMap<MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference, Integer>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference m = new MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference();
        while(true) {
            m.run();
        }
    }

    private void run() {

        MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference mm = new MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference();
        WeakReference<MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference> ref = new WeakReference<MemoryLeaksWithMapsWeakReference>(mm);
        mm = null;
        map.put(ref.get(), 1);
        System.out.println(map.size());
    }
}
```

Now, if an object is weakReferenced, it should get deleted by the garbage collector. However, in the case presented above (inserted into a Map), it is not. Can someone tell why map entries (weak reference) are not getting destroyed  ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ? Anyway, they may not be GC'd becauss the GC consider them as still used ( that is true) or maybe because the GC isn't called at all.

Comment: This example code is quite horrible by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref.get() returns null or hard reference to your object. So map will not contain any 'weak' reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you put an object (`ref.get()`) to a hash map, you create hard reference inside the map, so the object cannot be garbage collected.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Comment: You do not create a hard reference to the referant of a weak reference by putting it in a map or any type of collection, which seems to be what the question is.